# Public SVN setup

Tags: svn, public

I have an account with the shared hosting, IXwebhosting, will I be able to install a public SVN? if not, what server requirements I would need? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IXWebhosting doesn't offer shell access on their shared accounts. So no, you cannot install a public subversion server. For most providers you will probably need a VPS (Virtual Private Server) account to do things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to provide a public service for other to create SVN repositories or just create a public repository to use? If you want to create a public repository to use you could just use http://www.assembla.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Contact IXwebhosting... You would need a webserver (typically Apache) with DAV enabled, subversion installed (of course) and shell access to create and maintain the repository (which could be done by them, if they are nice)